# Why the results in mse are different between Tensorflow and Pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I tried to train and test a data set. By changing from TensorFlow to PyTorch, the mean square error is a slightly different during training and in the testing phase. However, the neural networks and hyper parameters are the same. The input are 70 entries,two hidden layers with 40 neurons, and 2 outputs. The hyper parameters are Adam optimizer with learning rate of 0.001, epsilon 1e-08 and 600 epochs.  Why this happened or it should not be the same results?

Thank you

TensorFlow code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

train_df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(70,))
x = layers.Dense(40, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(40, activation='relu')(x)

# Output
outputs = layers.Dense(2, )(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='my_model')
new_model = model.compile(loss=losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, epsilon=1e-08))

inputs = train_df.iloc[:, 0:70].to_numpy()
print(type(inputs))
targets = train_df.iloc[:, 70:72].to_numpy()
print(type(targets))
epochs = 600

for epoch in range(0, epochs):
    print("Epoch: " + str(epoch + 1))
    model.fit(inputs, targets, epochs=1, )

test_df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

inputTest = test_df.iloc[:, 0:70].to_numpy()
targetTest = test_df.iloc[:, 70:72].to_numpy()

outputTest = model.predict(inputTest)
mse = np.mean(np.power(targetTest - outputTest, 2), axis=1)
totalMse = mse.mean()
print("The mean square error is : " + str(totalMse))
```

PyTorch code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn

train_df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')

class newModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(newModel, self).__init__()
        self._layers = 40
        self._output_dim = 2
        self._linear_one = nn.Linear(70, self._layers)
        self._linear_two = nn.Linear(self._layers, self._layers)
        self._linear_three = nn.Linear(self._layers, self._output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self._linear_one(x))
        x = F.relu(self._linear_two(x))
        output = (self._linear_three(x))
        return output


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
model = newModel()
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 600
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

inputs = train_df.iloc[:, 0:70].to_numpy()
targets = train_df.iloc[:, 70:72].to_numpy()

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs.astype(np.float32))
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets.astype(np.float32))
inputs = torch.reshape(inputs, (-1, 70)).to(device)
targets = torch.reshape(targets, (-1, 2)).to(device)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # forward feed
    y_pred = model.forward(inputs)

    loss = criterion(y_pred, targets)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))

test_df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

inputs = test_df.iloc[:, 0:70].to_numpy()
targets = test_df.iloc[:, 70:72].to_numpy()

inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs.astype(np.float32))
inputs = torch.reshape(inputs, (-1, 70)).to(device)

outputs = model.forward(inputs).detach().numpy()

mse = np.mean(np.power(targets - outputs, 2), axis=1)
totalMse = mse.mean()
print("The mean square error is : " + str(totalMse))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would they be equal? If you haven't loaded weights on your network then their parameters will remain random. This is the behaviour when initializing parametrized layers.

Comment: OK, but I was wondering if my implementation in PyTorch is correct or not? given that the results are slightly different between TensorFlow and PyTorch. But I understand your point about the weights.

Comment: It looks ok, you can always do a quick check by setting all parameters to an arbitrary value and verifying both outputs match.

Comment: ok, an arbitrary value do you mean the inputs in the network, and check that the output of the network is equal to the target?

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. You can set *"all parameters to an arbitrary value"*, your model's parameter... and use the same input on both of these models.